# Is it possible to generate source xml by reversing a Qt .qm message file?

Tags: qt, localization, translation

[Qt Linguist or lrelease](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/linguist-translators.html#file-types) are the tools used to generate binary .qm Qt message files.

Is there any way to reverse the process that generates a .qm file?

The goal is to reverse a .qm file and recompile it with some modifications but without access to the original source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qt Linguist can open compiled .qm files for edit.  No need to generate source xml.

.qm files are not listed by default in the File | Open dialog.  Change the file filter in the dialog to `*.*` to display and load .qm files.

Comment: I tried your method, but it throws the following error "Cannot read file with specified input codec". Any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: @pkExec maybe a versioning difference?  At the time of my answer, I think I used binaries from Qt 3 or 4.  Maybe with Qt 5, things have changed.

Comment: To open Qt Linguist go to the directory where Qt is installed, open the wanted version's subdirectory then `gcc_64/bin` and run `linguist`. For me the full path is `/home/username/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/bin/linguist`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read the sources and try to find it out yourself? Hint: The relevant function seems to be

```
static bool saveQM(const Translator &translator, QIODevice &dev, ConversionData &cd)
```

in file QTDIR/tools/linguist/shared/qm.cpp.