# How can I convert qm to ts file?

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qt5, qt5.4

I'm using Qt 4.5 to translate a `.ts` file to a `.qm` file.
But now I've lost the `.ts` file.

How can I convert it back - from `.qm` to `.ts`?

Comment: What `qt` file did you loose? You can create ts files based on your sources.

Answer (score 20):

Use lconvert

```
lconvert compiled.qm -o source.ts
```

Comment: hello, what's lconvert, how can I found it. thank you too much.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu, `lconvert` is provided by the `qt4-dev-tools` and `qttools5-dev-tools` packages.

Comment: In MSYS2/UCRT64, package urct64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-qt6-tools includes lconvert-qt6

Answer (score 1):

There is also a tool named **QTLinguist** with GUI (Windows/Mac) to edit .ts/.po and others... It can also load .qm files choosing no loading filter `(*.*)`, then you can save the translation as .ts:

https://github.com/lelegard/qtlinguist-installers/releases/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

qm files are compiled translation files of ts files and there is no current tool to convert from qm to ts file (with my previous searches).
however if you want to hold current translations in your qm file and add new translations to your widgets or you want to edit some translations in your qm file : you can add new translator to your system by creating a new translation file.
From qt documentation :

> QCoreApplication::installTranslator : Adds the translation file
>   translationFile to the list of translation files to be used for
>   translations.
>
> Multiple translation files can be installed. Translations are searched
>   for in the reverse order in which they were installed, so the most
>   recently installed translation file is searched first and the first
>   translation file installed is searched last. The search stops as soon
>   as a translation containing a matching string is found.

So load other translation file after loading your qm file whose ts file is lost.

```
        translator1->load("yourqmfilewhosetsislost.qm");
        QCoreApplication::installTranslator(translator1);
        translator2->load("yournewqmfilewithneworeditedtranslations.qm");
        QCoreApplication::installTranslator(translator2);
```

Comment: Oh thanks. So I can load new translation over the old qm file. I've searched and found nothing about tool convert qm to ts.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Linguist can open compiled .qm files for edit/modification without need to generate source ts file.

.qm files are not listed by default in the File | Open dialog. Change the file filter in the dialog to *.* to display and load .qm files.

*(answer copied from question [Is it possible to generate source xml by reversing a Qt .qm message file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238265/) that was closed as a duplicate of this question though it predated this question by several years)*